# List with duplicated values and suffix

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, suffix

I have a list, `a`:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
```

and need to duplicate some values with the suffix `_ind` added this way (order is important):

```
['a', 'a_ind', 'b', 'b_ind', 'c', 'c_ind']
```

I tried:

```
b = [[x, x + '_ind'] for x in a]
c = [item for sublist in b for item in sublist]
print (c)
['a', 'a_ind', 'b', 'b_ind', 'c', 'c_ind']
```

Is there some better, more pythonic solution?

Comment: For the record, there's nothing wrong with this solution.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You could make it a generator:

```
def mygen(lst):
    for item in lst:
        yield item
        yield item + '_ind'

>>> a = ['a','b','c']
>>> list(mygen(a))
['a', 'a_ind', 'b', 'b_ind', 'c', 'c_ind']
```

You could also do it with `itertools.product`, `itertools.starmap` or `itertools.chain` or nested comprehensions but in most cases I would prefer a simple to understand, custom generator-function.

---

With python3.3, you can also use `yield from`—generator delegation—to make this elegant solution just a bit more concise:

```
def mygen(lst):
    for item in lst:
        yield from (item, item + '_ind')
```

Comment: Might I suggest a list comprehension version? `list([((yield x), (yield (x + '_ind'))) for x in a]) ; ['a', 'a_ind', 'b', 'b_ind', 'c', 'c_ind']`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Wtf... never seen such "inline" yield. Played with it some more, this works as well: `list([(yield from (x, x + '_ind')) for x in a])`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Killer. Want to post an answer with it? If not, I'll edit mine. :p

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You do it. I don't even know how that works :-)

Comment: At first I thought there was weird side effect shenanigans happening here, but no...I don't think so...damn..this is nice.

Comment: @StefanPochmann It's py3k only. They added yield support for list comps to allow generators to be created.

Comment: @idjaw Yeah, python is full of easter eggs like this. I didn't even know yields could exist inside list comprehensions, but lo and behold they can, and they result in generators, not lists :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ lol. PyCharm is reporting this as a syntax error (but still runs fine) even with a py3 interpreter attached. I think I'll see if there is a bug reported for it already.

Comment: @idjaw Oh wait, just saw the red underlines on my IDE too. xD

Comment: This seems to be by far the best way: simple, readable and efficient, no need for any other approaches

Answer (score 30):

It can be shortened a little bit by moving the options to the inner for loop in the list comprehension:

```
a = ['a','b','c']

[item for x in a for item in (x, x + '_ind')]
# ['a', 'a_ind', 'b', 'b_ind', 'c', 'c_ind']
```

Answer (score 15):

Another alternative with splicing (Python2.x, 3.x):

```
result = [None] * len(a) * 2
result[::2], result[1::2] = a, map(lambda x: x + '_ind', a)

result
# ['a', 'a_ind', 'b', 'b_ind', 'c', 'c_ind']
```

Comment: _"Python 3.x only"_ - Actually it's only Python 3.3 and greater. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380)

Comment: @ChristianDean Thanks. Added the link.

Comment: Do you need both the `list` call and the (list comprehension?) brackets?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, because a list comp with yield returns a generator.

Comment: This option is most useful if you want to obfuscate your Python code.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ No, for code golf Psidom's answer wins. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `itertools.chain()`:

```
import itertools

l = ['a','b','c']

new_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[i, i+"_ind"] for i in l]))

print new_list
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a_ind', 'b', 'b_ind', 'c', 'c_ind']
```

Comment: I would use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable). That way you don't need the unpacking with `*`

Comment: Alt: `list(itertools.chain(*zip(a, [x + '_ind' for x in a])) )` or `list(itertools.chain(*zip(a, map(lambda x: x + '_ind', a))))`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Agreed, but again, `chain.from_iterable` would IMHO be a bit cleaner :) `list(chain.from_iterable(zip(a, [i+'_ind' for i in a])))`. Not that it is particularly important.

Answer (score 5):

Before list comprehensions and generators were invented/became widespread, people used to think much simpler<sup>1</sup>:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> b = []
>>> for x in a: b.extend([x, x+'_ind'])
... 
>>> b
['a', 'a_ind', 'b', 'b_ind', 'c', 'c_ind']
```

---

<sup>*</sup> I don't mean that those constructs/tools are evil, just wanted to point out that there is a simple solution.

Comment: As far as I know were comprehensions and generators invented (implemented) to make these "constructs and tools" simpler (and definitely a lot faster). But I guess that's a quite opinion-based statement so YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

Since you asked for "simple", I thought I'd throw this in (albeit, maybe not the `pythonic` way):

```
for i in mylist: 
    mylist1.append(i);
    mylist1.append(i + '_ind');
```