# How to Concate 2 dataframes horizontally (row and col wise)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes

df1

```
  Cols/Rows   A    B    C
0         A   50  150  200
1         B  200  250  300
2         C  350  400  450
```

df2

```
  Cols/Rows    A    B    C
0         A   50  150  200
1         B  200  300  300
2         C  370  400  450
```

My expected output

```
  Cols/Rows    A    A2    B     B2    C    C2
0         A   50    50   150    150  200   200
1         B  200    200  250    300  300   300
2         C  350    370  400    400  450   450
```

I want to create new dataframe merging both with col and row wise. I tried to use `merge()` but it didn't worked

```
print(df2.merge(df1, how='left'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and parameter `suffixes` and then for columns names for change order is used [this perfect solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45122198/2901002):

```
df = df2.merge(df1, how='left', on='Cols/Rows', suffixes=['','2'])
print (df)
  Cols/Rows    A    B    C   A2   B2   C2
0         A   50  150  200   50  150  200
1         B  200  300  300  200  250  300
2         C  370  400  450  350  400  450

def mygen(lst):
    for item in lst:
        yield item
        yield item + '2'

#first column removed by indexing
cols = ['Cols/Rows'] + list(mygen(df1.columns[1:]))
df = df[cols]
print (df)
  Cols/Rows    A   A2    B   B2    C   C2
0         A   50   50  150  150  200  200
1         B  200  200  300  250  300  300
2         C  370  350  400  400  450  450
```

Last if need add difference new columns is better use changed [jpp solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51045022/2901002), because need subtract columns aligned by first col:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Cols/Rows')
df2 = df2.set_index('Cols/Rows')
df3 = df2.sub(df1)

df = df2.join(df1.add_suffix(2)).join(df3.add_suffix(3))
print (df)
             A    B    C   A2   B2   C2  A3  B3  C3
Cols/Rows                                          
A           50  150  200   50  150  200   0   0   0
B          200  300  300  200  250  300   0  50   0
C          370  400  450  350  400  450  20   0   0

def mygen(lst):
    for item in lst:
        yield item
        yield item + '2'
        yield item + '3'

df = df[list(mygen(df1.columns))].reset_index()
print (df)
  Cols/Rows    A   A2  A3    B   B2  B3    C   C2  C3
0         A   50   50   0  150  150   0  200  200   0
1         B  200  200   0  300  250  50  300  300   0
2         C  370  350  20  400  400   0  450  450   0
```

Comment: not sure why I am getting `KeyError: 'Cols/Rows'` even though I have checked and passed the correct column name,

Comment: Aahh, got it, can we re-arrange columns as well like `A A2 B B2` I don't want to loose the order, Yes we can sorted columns but in real world columns may be `Trade Trade2 All All2`

Comment: My whole idea is to get the difference between number `A - A2`

Comment: Yes that's the whole idea, but I was thinking to go step by step

Comment: @TarunK - Added solution for difference of columns

Answer (score 5):

`merge` have `suffixes`

```
df1.merge(df2,on='Cols/Rows',suffixes =['','2'],how='left')
Out[225]: 
  Cols/Rows    A    B    C   A2   B2   C2
0         A   50  150  200   50  150  200
1         B  200  250  300  200  300  300
2         C  350  400  450  370  400  450
```

Answer (score 4):

You can align indices and use `pd.DataFrame.join`:

```
res = df1.set_index('Cols/Rows')\
         .join(df2.set_index('Cols/Rows').add_suffix(2))

print(res)

             A    B    C   A2   B2   C2
Cols/Rows                              
A           50  150  200   50  150  200
B          200  250  300  200  300  300
C          350  400  450  370  400  450
```

Use `reset_index` as a final step to elevate your index to a series.